# Count with sqlsrv: sqlsrv_fetch_array() expects parameter 2 to be long

Tags: php, sql, sqlsrv

So before I used the sqlsrv function I was using the MySQL function.

The code worked perfect for me, but now that i have replaced the MySQL function by sqlsrv it gives me this error.

```
sqlsrv_fetch_array() expects parameter 2 to be long
```

The code is used to count is this:

```
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
$tsql = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE username = '".($_SESSION['username'])."'";
$res = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql);
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($res, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {

$aantalATV = $row['ATV'];
$aanvragenATV = "SELECT COUNT(soort) AS totaal FROM goedgekeurd WHERE username = '".($_SESSION['username'])."' AND soort='ATV' ";
$rowATV = sqlsrv_fetch_array($conn, $aanvragenATV);
$aantalATV= $aantalATV - $rowATV[0];
echo "aantal ATV dagen resterende:" .$aantalATV."<br />";
}
```

where is the problem, is it the query that needs to be changed?

Any help is appreciated!

New code snippet based on the answer of: Rikesh

```
$aantalATV = $row['ATV'];
$aanvragenATV = "SELECT COUNT(soort) AS totaal FROM goedgekeurd WHERE  username = '".($_SESSION['username'])."' AND soort='ATV' ";
$res = sqlsrv_query($conn, $aanvragenATV);
$rowATV = sqlsrv_fetch_array($res, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC);
$aantalATV= $aantalATV - $rowATV[0];
echo "aantal ATV dagen resterende:" .$aantalATV."<br />";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You using `sqlsrv_fetch_array` incorrectly second time.

```
sqlsrv_fetch_array($conn, $aanvragenATV);
```

[sqlsrv_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-fetch-array.php) take first parameter as sql statement & second fetch type. So change it to,

```
sqlsrv_fetch_array($aanvragenATV,SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC);
```

**Note:** It seems from your code you have used `$rowATV[0]` you need to fetch it by type `NUMERIC` or else change it as per your need.

Comment: working like a charm, but there is another line needed so that the $conn variable can be closed out. I will post the new script.